# How does Chrome devTools create General Header for a request?

Tags: ajax, http, cors, google-chrome-devtools, jqxhr

According to [the docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/reference#headers:%7E:text=In%20the%20General%20section%2C%20DevTools%20shows%20you%20human%2Dreadable%20status%20message%20next%20to%20the%20received%20HTTP%20status%20code):

> In the General section, DevTools shows you human-readable status message next to the received HTTP status code.

How is the status code in this General section created?

I'm developing code that sends requests and interprets error messages using jQuery Ajax.  Because of CORS configuration, I can't see the status code in the response header from the server.  Why can the Devtools see this status code even though the server does not have CORS setup correctly?

The status code I receive is `0`, while I would expect something like `401`.

Comment: Devtools is allowed to use this internal info because it's a part of the browser, a web page can't do it.

Comment: If the requested resource is configured for CORS and allows the Web origin of your client, the latter would have access to the human-readable status message. With the Fetch API, it's available via the `Response.statusText` property.

Comment: @jub0bs The requested resource is NOT configured for CORS.  That is why I'm confused.  How can DevTools read the status code if there is no CORS configuration?

Comment: @wOxxOm can you go into further detail?  I would expect the browser is using the same type of "xhr".  Are there any resources you can provide that explains your theory?

Comment: Devtools is a part of the browser, so it naturally has access to all the internals of network requests. It's not a theory, you can see the source code for yourself.

Comment: wOxxOm is correct. The DevTools show you more than what is accessible to the client, i.e. the script that requests the resource.

Comment: @jub0bs I'm assuming this is correct but are there any resources/dosc that prove this?  I can't find anything.

Comment: @wOxxOm Same as my comment above.  Are there any resources that prove this?  I haven't been able to find anything.  Thank you for your comments.

Comment: You can see the [source code for chromium and devtools](https://www.google.com/search?q=chromium%7Cdevtools+source+code). It's open source. You can also debug/inspect the devtools itself by using [devtools-on-devtools](/q/12291138).

Comment: @BigBen_Davy Perhaps read more about the Same-Origin Policy. Its purpose is to restrict clients, not the browser itself. That should lift your confusion.

Comment: Thanks for the comments so far, but I think my original question still persists.  "How is the status code in this General section created?"

Comment: @BigBen_Davy Status code? It comes from the server. If you're referring to the human-readable status text, either it comes from the server, or perhaps (I'm not sure) Chrome generates it if the status code is a standard one (e.g. 405 => _Method Not Allowed_).